# Windows command prompt custom commands

Tags: windows, cmd

I am looking for a way to customise some of the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) commands. I would like the new command to be called instead of the one defined by Windows to do almost the same thing except some minor customisations. An example could be with the pushd command print a message saying which directory is changing to. This could be useful, for example, to have the output a .bat script parsed by another tool.

As an example, pushd.bat would look like:

```
@echo off
pushd %1
echo Entering directory `%cd%'
```

...but where should I put this so that it gets called instead of the internal command pushd?

Comment: You can't replace or change internal commands. But you can use `pushd.bat %1` to explicitly use your version. (Btw - if it would work as you described, your script would execute another instance of itself instead of the original `pushd` command, which would execute another instance of itself etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You should not customize internal commands because some of these commands go all the way back to DOS and have hidden bugs and features that some tools might rely on and it is unlikely that you will implement them correctly.

You can add custom aliases with `doskey`. These are better than batch files. They allow you to add certain mini scripts that help you in your daily command line usage. These can actually override the names of internal commands.

```
doskey pushd=echo Entering $*^&pushd $*
pushd c:\Windows
```

You can add your `doskey` commands to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` in the registry but you really need to [be careful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433) if you use it to change existing commands. I recommend that you invent new names for your commands.

Comment: Note that `doskey` macros don't work in batch files (because basically they intercept and translate keyboard input)